# Python only mysql.connector replacement with compatible api for mariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying out this command, but it fails miserably:

python: MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.1.3, found version 3.0.3 on ubuntu 18.04

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C >= 3.1.3, found version 3.0.3

is there a non c version of mysql.connector compatible with the latest mariadb?

Answer (score -1):

the problem was I was connecting to one db with a user which was not authorized to do the thing on the other db. the error message did not include the DB name.

double check the db name is correct on the query itself.